# problem - upgrade 15.10 to 16.04 , 404 not found

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, package-management, 15.10

It is my first question on this website. I am newbie, I am using dual boot on my dell laptop with windows 10 and ubuntu 15.10. I want my Ubuntu 15.10 upgraded to 16.04. Currently, I can do **`sudo apt-get update`** , **`sudo apt-get upgrade`** and **`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`** on my Ubuntu 15.10 without any problem, but when I use **`sudo update-manager -d`** and proceed further

[image]

There were options:

```
Upgrading Ubuntu to version 16.04 
Preparing to upgrade  
Setting new software channels  
Getting new packages  
Installing the upgrades  
Cleaning up  
Restarting the computer
```

After finishing first step, on second step **Setting new software channels** , after some times it shows:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/source/Sources 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80],  
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80],  
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80],  
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

But, when I go to these websites, I find Sources, Packages file only in the form of `Sources.gz/tz` , `Packages.gz/tz`. I do not know how to configure, whatever is needed, so that it can extract `Sources.gz/tz` and `Packages.gz/tz` without any 404:not found sign.

Please, help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do a fresh install of 16.04. 15.10 is not supported.

Comment: @Pilot6 Is there no other way to upgrade to 16.04 without removing Ubuntu 15.10 completely ?

Comment: @Pilot6: Upgrading unsupported releases to supported releases is *always* on topic.

Comment: Do you use an HTTP proxy of some sort? What's the output of `wget -qSO /dev/null http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-i386/Packages`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I do not agree. There is no supported way to upgrade EoL releases. The only valid answer is re-install.

Comment: @Pilot6: What? Once supported upgrade paths remain supported beyond the support life of the source releases at least as long as the target release receives support. The procedure remainst exactly the same before the release lost support (except for potentially different package sources). There's even a protected question about it: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](/q/91815/175814)

Comment: This is is an exceptional question like "How I remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on" that is off-topic, but the community agreed to leave it.

Comment: @Pilot6: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14292/errors-while-upgrading-from-a-eol-release-should-the-question-be-closed says quite the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the update manager, do you have 'New distribution release '16.04' available' message? You can click it and follow the procedure.

If not, you can do it from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Edit: Can't find equivalent for desktop, but server guide says do-release-upgrade is recommended:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html

Also, there's a difference between dist-upgrade and do-release-upgrade as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/322810/whats-the-difference-between-apt-get-dist-upgrade-and-do-release-upgrade)

Comment: thanks but the error is same, only now it is shown in terminal.

Comment: W:Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/source/Sources 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80] 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-amd64/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80] 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-i386/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80] 
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or 
old ones used instead. 

Restoring original system state
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done  ......